# Instrucciones de no uso de una etiqueta

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, extracto-de-etiquetas

Revisando [ésta etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/351772) me encontré que dice:

> **NO UTILIZAR**: fragmento es una etiqueta ambigua, utilizada para referirse a numerosas tecnologías.

Por lo que me hace pensar que lo que se sugiere es mas bien una intervención para enlistanegrar dicha etiqueta.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido esa edición. Si no se debe usar la etiqueta, a mi gusto, deberíamos matarla... Si no, la ayuda de la etiqueta debe decir cuando usarla...

Comment: @gbianchi se uso como referencia lo que esta en el sitio en ingles.

Comment: @gbianchi si la etiqueta del sitio en ingles tiene un significado diferente o si la tematica del uso de etiquetas entre el sitio en español y el sitio en ingles es distinto; cual es el Criterio correcto con el cual se deben crear los extractos y detalles de las etiquetas... no hay nada definido al respecto.

Comment: @gbianchi Si por ejemplo se quema la etiqueta al final vendra otro usuario y la va a volver a crear .... o tu garantizas que no sera asi?

Comment: @gbianchi  sugieron que si una etiqueta es ambigua debe indicar que otras etiquetas deben usarce... de tal manera comparto el mismo criterio con el que se edito la etiqueta del sitio en ingles.

Comment: les comparto el historial del sitio en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5220993/revisions quien ha estado detras de esto en el sitio en ingles ha sido una serie de moderadore y usuarios de haya. saludos.

Comment: gracias Israel por darte cuenta que no tengo acentos en este teclado :)